# Can't navigate to new page windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

when I add a new page to my Project and use "Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2xaml)); " Visual studio does not recognize my page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DovKq.png
How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Someone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Capitalize your xaml page name (Emergencias) and then try Frame.Navigate(typeof(Emergencias));

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyPage));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page is named TestPage.xaml then your code should be

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(TestPage));
```